# Outlook VBA - Item.Move procedure fails randomly

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the code below.

The problem with it, is that, while everything else works perfectly (categories are assigned and saved successfully), sometimes, randomly, the emails do not get moved. I've searched a lot and was not able to come up with a solution, perhaps someone can help. This happens regardless of it is a mailitem or other type, and happens randomly, not with specific folders. Sometimes, if trying multiple times with the same email, it ends up moving. Any help is appreciated!

***What the code is supposed to do is:
1) Email arrives
2) User assigns a category
3) Code proceeds to add another category with the user name of who assigned the first category
4) Email proceeds to get moved to a folder named exactly as the category assigned***

```
 Private WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myOlItems = GetFolder("SHARED MAILBOX NAME\Inbox").Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Not Item Is Nothing Then
        Dim status As Outlook.UserProperty
        Set status = Item.UserProperties.Find("Processed")
        If Not Item Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Cat = Item.Categories
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        On Error Resume Next
        If Cat <> "" And status <> "True" And Not Cat Is Nothing Then
            If Len(Cat) > 0 Then
                user = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser
                user = Replace(user, ",", " ")
                Item.Categories = Cat & ";Category " & Cat & " assigned by: " & user
                status.Value = "True"
                Item.Save
                Item.Move (GetFolder("SHARED MAILBOX\Inbox").Folders("Subfolder name").Folders(Cat))
                Cat = Nothing
                status = Nothing
                Set myOlItems = GetFolder("SHARED MAILBOX NAME\Inbox").Items
            End If
        ElseIf Cat = "" And status = "True" Then
            status.Value = "False"
            status = Nothing
            Cat = Nothing
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example!

Comment: My apologies, example of what exactly?

Comment: How to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Got it, I decided to post the entire thing just because it's a really short code, doesn't have much to go through. My apologies if it's too long

Comment: The code you posted is way too long for a minimal example. This will significantly reduce the amount of people willing to look at your problem!

Comment: You do a bunch of stuff after the second On Error Resume Next, replace it with an On Error GoTo & add some logging code to store any error details that may provide insight into what the issue actually is.

Comment: Tried to trim as much as possible. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Put Option Explicit at the top of the module. Declare Cat as a String variable. You will find you have to drop all Cat = Nothing code.

Remove the second `On Error Resume Next`. Once the line is removed you will find you need to `Set Status = Nothing`. Avoid hiding errors with `On Error Resume Next` until you know how it can be made useful. See here for Error Handling information http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

This may reliably do what you want.

```
Option Explicit ' At the top of the module

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

    Dim Cat As String
    Dim uSer As String

    If Not Item Is Nothing Then

        Dim status As Outlook.UserProperty
        Set status = Item.UserProperties.Find("Processed")

        If Not Item Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next 'This line does nothing
            Cat = Item.Categories
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If

        ' http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm
        'On Error Resume Next

        'If Cat <> "" And status <> "True" And Not Cat Is Nothing Then
        If Cat <> "" And status <> "True" Then

            If Len(Cat) > 0 Then

                uSer = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser
                uSer = Replace(uSer, ",", " ")
                Item.Categories = Cat & ";Category " & Cat & " assigned by: " & uSer
                status.Value = "True"
                Item.Save
                Item.move (GetFolder("SHARED MAILBOX\Inbox").folders("Subfolder name").folders(Cat))
                'Cat = Nothing

                ' status = Nothing
                Set status = Nothing

                'Set myOlItems = GetFolder("SHARED MAILBOX NAME\Inbox").items

            End If

        ElseIf Cat = "" And status = "True" Then
            status.Value = "False"
            'status = Nothing
            Set status = Nothing
            'Cat = Nothing

        End If

        'On Error GoTo 0

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I will be testing this and come back to you.

Comment: I've tested the code above and was able to track the error down to the following line: theFolder = GetFolder("SHARED MAILBOX\Inbox").Folders("SubFolder").Folders(Cat) - It seems upper/lower case is not an issue, as regardless of how the category is named, it moves some of the emails as long as the name is the same. However, it seems that in some cases, the folder is not found, which is why it fails to move. Furthermore, it's not an issue linked to the specific folder as it fails with folders that previously had items succesfully moved to them. I can post the GetFolder method if you'd like

Comment: My apologies on the double posting but wanted this to be on a separate message - The error, after breaking down even further, is when trying to obtain the first subfolder under the inbox.

Comment: If you have determined that Outlook has forgotten where to find the subfolder there may not be a solution. A second method of referencing the folder failed here but you could try it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894650/outlook-forgets-subfolders-in-shared-e-mail You could try a third method of referencing folders if the folder is in your navigation pane. Session.folders("SHARED MAILBOX NAME").folders("Inbox").Folders("Subfolder name").Folders(Cat)

Comment: I was able to identify that this issue happens because of the Cache Mode. If we uncheck the "Download Shared Folders" in the data file properties, the issue gets fixed, but Outlook works extremely slow when setting it up that way, so I will be trying the Session alternative and see if that helps. Thank you!

Comment: Did the following: Set theInbox = Session.Folders("SHARED FOLDER NAME").Folders("Inbox")
                    Set theSub = theInbox.Folders("Subfolder") ---- the Inbox is located just fine, every time, but when attempting the set theSub with the Subfolder, it returns Nothing (Once again, sometimes)